# How to make sense of the active_plugins option_value to enable and disable certain plugins from the database?

Tags: plugins, database

Can anyone explain how to interpret and make sense of the active_plugins option_value string in WordPress. And then use this string/ array to disable and activate specific plugins?

Here is an example:

```
a:8:{i:0;s:21:"adrotate/adrotate.php";i:1;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:2;s:33:"better-related/better-related.php";i:3;s:17:"clicky/clicky.php";i:4;s:49:"custom-post-permalinks/custom-post-permalinks.php";i:5;s:32:"disqus-comment-system/disqus.php";i:6;s:33:"export-to-text/export-to-text.php";i:7;s:36:"google-sitemap-generator/sitemap.php";}
```

Comment: You can use the [find and replace function within the Migrate DB plugin to disable individual plugins](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172398/deactivate-plugins-using-migrate-dbs-find-and-replace-options). You can't activate a plugin this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a serialized array.

```
// Serialized:
a:8:{i:0;s:21:"adrotate/adrotate.php";i:1;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:2;s:33:"better-related/better-related.php";i:3;s:17:"clicky/clicky.php";i:4;s:49:"custom-post-permalinks/custom-post-permalinks.php";i:5;s:32:"disqus-comment-system/disqus.php";i:6;s:33:"export-to-text/export-to-text.php";i:7;s:36:"google-sitemap-generator/sitemap.php";}

// dump:
var_dump( maybe_unserialize('a:8:{i:0;s:21:"adrotate/adrotate.php";i:1;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:2;s:33:"better-related/better-related.php";i:3;s:17:"clicky/clicky.php";i:4;s:49:"custom-post-permalinks/custom-post-permalinks.php";i:5;s:32:"disqus-comment-system/disqus.php";i:6;s:33:"export-to-text/export-to-text.php";i:7;s:36:"google-sitemap-generator/sitemap.php";}') );

// Result
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "adrotate/adrotate.php"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "akismet/akismet.php"
  [2]=>
  string(33) "better-related/better-related.php"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "clicky/clicky.php"
  [4]=>
  string(49) "custom-post-permalinks/custom-post-permalinks.php"
  [5]=>
  string(32) "disqus-comment-system/disqus.php"
  [6]=>
  string(33) "export-to-text/export-to-text.php"
  [7]=>
  string(36) "google-sitemap-generator/sitemap.php"
}
```

Use `maybe_unserialize()` or `unserialize()` to transform it back to an array.

Comment: Cool. But is it possible to edit the array and disable and activate specific plugins?

Comment: Assuming you know the plugin's "slug" (eg. something retrieved with `plugin_basename` yes.  You should take a look at the core functions `activate_plugin` and `deactivate_plugins` and see how they work to get an idea how to accomplish what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very heavy duty in comparison with JSON! Though also not too hard.

Here's mine before modification. I want to disable Google Authenticator to allow myself to log in again. My provider now provides HTTPS for free thankfully, though before this I relied on authenticator as a protection against password sniffing. It's still a very useful feature to have, HTTPS or not. So I intend to reset and re-enable it once my phone has a new token for it.

[image: active_plugins value before edit]

It looks like "Array, length 5" and for each item "Index, Length, Value". I've highlighted the entry for Authenticator. My modification was to delete this entry, modify the array length to 4 and reduce the index values for all subsequent entries.

Here's the diff showing the change. I've formatted it for easier read here. I wouldn't expect it to work if formatted like this!

[image: diff showing change made]

Answer (score 0):

I had more than a few times where I could NOT disable plugins on our Wordpress site, and the only avenue was database access. I could read/write to the DB, so I made this python tool to list the plugins in human-readable form; delete them from the list by line number; save the delete plugin entries to a backup file; and create a new PHP string to insert back into the database.

As I drew inspiration partly from this thread, I thought I'd add a link to it here:
https://github.com/Solarbotics/Wordpress_plugin_managment_by_db