# Plugin fatal error

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to activate a plugin I made on a network site. I'm getting an error:

```
Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
```

I have the debug mode on and it outputs all errors into a debug.log, however nothing is given for this error.

Is there another way to see what the error may be?

The plugin registers a CPT with taxonomy. It was recently deactivated to test a few changes I made. Upon the reactivation it is failing. Something to note, the custom post type has 900 posts and 1400 taxonomy terms. Hopefully something comes to light without having to redo all that work for the posts.

Comment: How big is the plugin?  Could you paste it into functions.php?  You might get better debugging information from there.

Comment: The plugin has several files associated with it. After messing around with it a bit more, I'm now getting a memory exhausted error. I presume this is due to the large amount of taxonomy terms and CPTs. So now it's a matter of figuring out how to retain the data.

Comment: "...nothing is given for this error." Um *SOMETHING* is giving the error :) If you deactivate the plugin does the error go away? Also if you see that error you should also have a line number/PHP error.

Comment: I was literally see nothing more than than "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error." my debug.log didn't even have anything of value, nor did the server error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually muscled my way through it. The first thing I did was [manually activated the plugin via the database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45109/how-to-make-sense-of-the-active-plugins-option-value-to-enable-and-disable-certa). Next I went back to the subsite to verify that the plugin was activated. It was not.

So I tried activating again. Now I was getting an error in relation to memory being exhausted. This was caused from the large amount of data for my CPT and taxonomy.

I had to export my post and taxonomy tables from the database, then delete everything, before I was able to activate the plugin.

After the plugin was active, I was able to import the posts and taxonomy terms back into their respective tables.